# Flexibles Leerzeichen oder Wortabstand bei akademischen Graden

Tags: typography

Wie sind das "flexible Leerzeichen" und der "Wortabstand" bei akademischen Graden zu nutzen?

Beispiel:

```
Prof. Dr. Dr. h. c. Eugen H. S. Egner
```

Typischerweise sieht man

```
Prof. Dr. Dr. h.c. Eugen H. S. Egner
```

Sei `|` das Zeichen für ein flexibles Leerzeichen und `#` das Zeichen für Wortabstand. Im Buch [Detailtypografie](https://typografie.de/produkt/detailtypografie/) wird in der 2. Auflage auf S. 17 folgendes vorgeschlagen:

```
Prof.|Dr.|Dr.|h.|c.|Eugen#H.|S.|Egner.
```

Ja, nach `h.|c.` geben die Autoren wirklich `|` an.

Im Duden, Band 1., 22. Auflage, findet sich auf S. 93 zu "Festabständen" nur Angaben zu Abkürzungen und Datumsangaben in Zahlen.

Ich würde folgendes vorschlagen:

```
Prof.|Dr.|Dr.|h.|c.#Eugen#H.|S.|Egner
```

Oder sogar folgendes, um semantisch zu gruppieren:

```
Prof.#Dr.#Dr.|h.|c.#Eugen#H.#S.#Egner
```

Wie ist es "korrekt" bzw. üblich?

Comment: Es sollte m.E. *gar kein* Leerzeichen (egal welcher Art) zwischen *h.* und *c.* stehen. *h.c.* (honoris causa) ist *eine* Abkürzung. Also Prof.|Dr.|Dr.|h.c.# usw. Ich würde sogar Prof.#Dr.#Dr.|h.c.#Eugen#H.|S.|Egner benutzen, um klar zu machen, dass das *h.c.* zum vorhergehenden *Dr.* gehört.

Comment: Aber ich sehe dass ich damit alleine stehe. Trotzdem bleibe ich bei meiner Meinung: h. aund c. sollten nicht getrennt geschrieben werden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl/dr** Wenn es richtig aussieht, dem Auftraggeber gefällt und konsistent im jeweiligen Schriftstück verwendet wird ist es auch richtig!

--

Wirkliche Regeln gibt es hierfür nicht. Mir sind auch keine "Din-Regeln" bekannt welche die Verwendung bei akademischen Titeln explizit regeln.

Nähern wir uns also von einer anderen Seite. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmales_Leerzeichen) sagt zum "schmalen Leerzeichen":

> Das schmale Leerzeichen soll die Leserlichkeit einer unübersichtlichen
>   Zeichengruppe verbessern, beispielsweise vielstellige Zahlen oder
>   Abkürzungen. Durch die Verwendung von schmalen Leerzeichen sind
>   einzelne Zeichengruppen schneller erkennbar und wirken besser
>   proportioniert. Im Unterschied zum üblichen Leerzeichen soll es jedoch
>   die Zusammengehörigkeit der Gruppe eindeutig erkennen lassen.

Davon ausgehend setze ich Titel immer in der vorgeschlagenen Form

> Prof.|Dr.|Dr.|h.|c.

Obwohl natürlich auch die semantische Ordnung ihren Reiz hat. Diese kann allerdings schnell unruhig wirken, wenn man Leerzeichen unterschiedlicher Breite so offensiv nebeneinander setzt.

Bei den Textteilen nach dem ausgeschriebenen Vornamen kann man streiten. Ich gehe davon aus, dass H. und S. weitere Vornamen und Egner der Nachname der Person ist. Um den Zusammenhang des gesamten Namens nicht zu zerreißen setze ich diese ebenfalls meist als

> H.|S.|Egner

Da zwischen Vorname und Nachname normalerweise immer ein ganzes Leerzeichen steht würde aus dem Namen ein

> Eugen#H.|S.|Egner

werden.

Die Frage ist nun, was man für einen Abstand zwischen Titel(n) und Namen packt. Wie gesagt, da es dafür keine verbindlichen Regeln gibt würde ich es nach Gefühl machen und lieber ein # setzen.

Entsprechend wäre ich ebenfalls für

> Prof.|Dr.|Dr.|h.|c.#Eugen#H.|S.|Egner

Aber auch hier gilt: Nimm das was besser gefällt oder noch besser, was dem Kunden/Auftraggeber besser gefällt.

Wichtig ist natürlich, dass wenn man einmal so anfangt sämtliche Titel und Namen in derselben Form setzt. Und traurig ist, dass die meisten den Unterschied erst gar nicht sehen ;) .

Für weitere Anregungen zu diesem Thema empfehle ich übrigens [diesen Thread](https://www.typografie.info/3/topic/25800-dr-rer-pol-halbes-oder-ganzes-leerzeichen/) bei typographie.info . Da wurde schon leidenschaftlich über diesen Punkt, bzw. Abstand diskutiert. (Sollte der Link zu einer Registrierungsaufforderung führen einfach in einem privaten Browsertab oder per Google-Cache öffnen. Bei häufiger Nutzung aber bitte so fair sein und sich im Forum anmelden)